# Currently, All my SQL Request showing "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suddenly, all of sql server requests showing "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out". What is the quickest way to find the issue?

```
Stack Trace: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352418
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1406
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +140
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +316
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1481
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
```

I got the SQl that is causing the blocking issue by,

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/script-open-transactions-with-text-and-plans/

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace? It seems there are a lot of reasons for this error.

Comment: @user960567 can you please post the updates as an answer and accept it so it will be helpful to others also

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here how I was able to find the issue,
First check all open transaction your database,

```
DBCC OPENTRAN ('Databse')
```

If there is an open transaction then Grab it's SPID and put it inside INPUTBUFFER

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER (58)
```

This will give you the actual SQL. If you want,you can kill this transaction,

```
KILL 58
```

BTW, In my application I can use READ COMMITTED data,

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Or

```
Select * from Products WITH NoLock
```

Here is another way to find the SQl quickly,

```
SELECT
    [s_tst].[session_id],
    [s_es].[login_name] AS [Login Name],
    DB_NAME (s_tdt.database_id) AS [Database],
    [s_tdt].[database_transaction_begin_time] AS [Begin Time],
    [s_tdt].[database_transaction_log_bytes_used] AS [Log Bytes],
    [s_tdt].[database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved] AS [Log Rsvd],
    [s_est].text AS [Last T-SQL Text],
    [s_eqp].[query_plan] AS [Last Plan]
FROM
    sys.dm_tran_database_transactions [s_tdt]
JOIN
    sys.dm_tran_session_transactions [s_tst]
ON
    [s_tst].[transaction_id] = [s_tdt].[transaction_id]
JOIN
    sys.[dm_exec_sessions] [s_es]
ON
    [s_es].[session_id] = [s_tst].[session_id]
JOIN
    sys.dm_exec_connections [s_ec]
ON
    [s_ec].[session_id] = [s_tst].[session_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.dm_exec_requests [s_er]
ON
    [s_er].[session_id] = [s_tst].[session_id]
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text ([s_ec].[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS [s_est]
OUTER APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan ([s_er].[plan_handle]) AS [s_eqp]
ORDER BY
    [Begin Time] ASC;
GO
```

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/script-open-transactions-with-text-and-plans/

Answer (score 4):

Try to execute this command:

```
exec sp_updatestats
```

Comment: This happen lot of time. I need to find the root cause?

Comment: is there any porting king of thing running on your SQL server ?? means is there any process which does bulk insert/update/delete in one or more table regularly after certain period ?? because this genraly comes because of indexes , stats

Comment: I don't have any index. This is simple table.

Comment: sorry i am not able think more on this .. i think you should try on dba.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com there is already one post regrdig this .. http://serverfault.com/questions/419997/the-wait-operation-timed-out-when-running-sql-server-in-hyper-v

Comment: perhaps your table should have an index - it makes searching data orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: this is my life saver, after I update statistics, everything was normal and no slow running queries thank you @Dhaval

Answer (score 1):

This type of SQL Server timeout error can occur on an attempt to INSERT or UPDATE a particular table, when a long-running SELECT query is currently executing on that table (depending on the isolation level of the SELECT).

Related:

- [SQL Server - does [SELECT] lock [UPDATE]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829529/sql-server-does-select-lock-update)
- [When should you use "with (nolock)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/sql-server-when-should-you-use-with-nolock)

Answer (score 0):

just stop and start sql server browser service again, it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem too but I managed to fix it.

Originally I had set all SQL Server services to be started manually by me. But this (after a while of starting just SQL Server (server_name), this error came up. To rememdy it, I found that SQL Server Browser and SQL Server Agent (server_name) needed to be started too.

SQL Server Agent (server_name) would not be started manually as it was not being used, so I set it back to automatic so it will start when another process uses it.

Answer (score 0):

For our case, issue was due to the following reasons:

1. A legacy application running .Net 4.0
2. Server was recently patched with the latest .Net patches (**as at 2018/11/08**)
3. The database in question was mirrored

There were no deadlocks and the client services as well as SQL Server were well-resourced.

### Our solution:

1) We tested a Roll-back of the patches/service pack and it worked (**Not recommended**)

2) **(Recommended)**: [According to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2605597/fix-time-out-error-when-a-mirrored-database-connection-is-created-by-t) , the conditions above set us up for the error:

> When an application uses the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 or Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 4 data provider for Microsoft SQL Server (SQLClient) to
>   connect to a mirrored database, you may receive the following error
>   message:
>
> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, UInt32 error) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean
>   encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean& marsCapable) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginWithFailover(Boolean
>   useFailoverHost, ServerInfo primaryServerInfo, String failoverHost,
>   String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer
>   timeout) Note If the ConnectionTimeout property is set to the default
>   value of 15 seconds, you may receive the error message after the
>   connection is open for 1.2 seconds.

### Cause

> This issue occurs because of an error in the **connection-retry
>   algorithm for mirrored databases.**
>
> When the retry-algorithm is used, the data provider waits for the
>   first read (SniReadSync) call to finish. The call is sent to the
>   back-end computer that is running SQL Server, and the waiting time is
>   calculated by multiplying the connection time-out value by 0.08.
>   However, the data provider incorrectly sets a connection to a doomed
>   state if a response is slow and if the first SniReadSync call is not
>   completed before the waiting time expires.
>
> Note The slow response in this case may be triggered either by the
>   server or by network latency.

Resolution

> This issue is **resolved in the .NET Framework 4.5.2**. In addition to the
>   .NET Framework 4.5.2, **there are hotfixes available for other .NET**
>   F**ramework versions**

---

More details and Hotfix download: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2605597/fix-time-out-error-when-a-mirrored-database-connection-is-created-by-t